# код yii2 выдает много ошибок после клонирования с git

Tags: yii2, git

После клонирования бэка c git код выдает очень много ошибок , там где их в принципе нет.
Например:

```
    $model = Card::find()->where(['id' => $cardUuid])- подчеркивает find() как ошибку и таких ошибок ну очень много.
```

так же код не запускается через wampserver.
Не подскажите что нужно сделать? уверен , что этот код рабочий

Comment: Папка vendor есть?

Comment: Скорее всего просто `composer install`